# Read input integer from external file for MPI

Tags: mpi

How could I read external input file for mpi? I need to read one integer from external file (zadanie4_vstup.txt), to compute simple factorial. I have tried to substitute the second argument in MPI_Init() with address of int variable (n), but it looks it is nonsense. 
Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    FILE *fr, *fw;

    fr = fopen("zadanie4_vstup.txt", "r");
    fw = fopen("zadanie4_vystup.txt", "w");


    int nproc, me;
    int fakt=1, i, buff, n;
    MPI_Status stat;

    fscanf(fr, "%d", &n);

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &me);

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) reduction(*:fakt)
    for(i=me*n/nproc+1; i<=(me+1)*n/nproc; i++) {
      fakt *= i;
    }

    if(nproc > 1) {
      if(me == 0) {
        for(i=1; i<nproc; i++) {
          MPI_Recv(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
          fakt*=buff;
        }
      } else {
        MPI_Send(&fakt, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      }
    }
    if(me == 0) {
      fprintf(fw, "%d! = %d\n", n, fakt);
    }

    fclose(fr);
    fclose(fw);

    MPI_Finalize();
```

}

Comment: first, you should only `fopen()/fclose()` `fw` on rank 0.

Comment: you might also want to read the input file only on rank 0 and then `MPI_Bcast()` it to all the other ranks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a version of your program that reads `n` on the command line.

note i simplified the communications by using `MPI_Reduce()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int nproc, me;
    int fakt=1, res, i, buff, n;
    MPI_Status stat;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &me);

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) reduction(*:fakt)
    for(i=me*n/nproc+1; i<=(me+1)*n/nproc; i++) {
      fakt *= i;
    }

    MPI_Reduce(&fakt, &res, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_PROD, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(me == 0) {
      printf("%d! = %d\n", n, res);
    }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

for example

```
$ mpirun -np 4 ./fakt 6
6! = 720
```

Comment: Thank you, Gilles

Comment: MPI_Reduce is good idea. But I still didn't resolve to take variable for factorial from external source. How can I put the source on rank0, please?

Comment: `if (0 == me) {
    FILE *fr = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fr, "%d", &n);
}
MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`